# Doubt about function value (expected undefined, but Wolframalpha says otherwise)

Tags: analysis, functions

I have the function $f(x) = 1 + \frac{12x+4}{\left( x+1 \right)^2} \cdot \left( \frac{12}{12x+4} - \frac{2}{x+1} \right)$ (actually the derivate of another function, but that shouldn't matter). Since $12x+4=0$ for $x=\frac{-1}{3}$ I would have said the function value is undefined at that point - but Wolframalpha says it's 28! Now what I *think* might have happened is that WA secretly showed me the limit of $x\to\frac{-1}{3}$ and just didn't bother to tell me. Or, am I missing something else?

Comment: What exactly did you type in WA? Obviously it canceled the $12x+4$!

Comment: 1 + (12x+4)/((x+1)^2) * (12/(12x+4) - 2/(x+1)), x=-1/3

Comment: That's OK. Removable singularities are for removing.

Comment: The function as you have expressed it is indeed undefined at $x=-\frac{1}{3}$. However, it does have a limit as $x \rightarrow -\frac{1}{3}$, so you can justifiably extend the definition of $f$ to that point.

Comment: -1 for Wolfram Alpha

Comment: I find it annoying that these details (if you consider it a detail) are usually glossed over without comment by teachers.

Comment: Actually, our Prof is very thorough when it comes to those kind of things, I just wasn't sure if it was actually ok to fix the singularity in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we consider function without multiplication ,yes it is undefined at $x=-1/3$  ,but we can remove it by multiplication ,so  after we execute this operation we get
$f(x)=1+12/(x+1)^2-(24*x+8)/(x+1)^3$,at  $x=-1/3$  yes $f(-1/3)$=28

Comment: Can I just do it like that? Granted, the original function is continuous at $-1/3$ so I can probably do that in this case, but are such things ok in general?

Comment: it depends,as others mentioned   ,it is like removable point,like in limits,so you may do it in some cases,but actually  i think that it requires some permision before do this

Comment: i hope it would help you,good lucks